# "Dedico a" vs. "dedico ao"

Tags: gramática, concordância

Quando a palavra seguinte é masculina, qual opção deve ser escolhida: "dedico a..." ou "dedico ao..."?

Por exemplo:

(A) Dedico este trabalho a meu filho.
(B) Dedico este trabalho ao meu filho.

Ambas as sentenças possuem diversos registros no google. **As duas formas estão corretas?**

Quando a palavra seguinte está no plural, também encontramos registros distintos. Por exemplo:

(C) Dedico este trabalho a meus pais.
(D) Dedico este trabalho aos meus pais.

**O plural altera alguma coisa relativamente ao caso anterior?**

Answer (score 1):

A questão aqui não é o verbo dedicar, mas antes o uso de artigo *o* com o pronome pessoal possessivo *meu* (no segundo par de frases, *os* e *meus*).

Em Portugal, o uso do artigo junto de possessivos pré-nominais (os nomes aqui sendo *filho* e *pais*) é praticamente obrigatório fora de situações particulares como frases feitas (como *em minha opinião*, *por minha conta*) e vocativos. Contudo, as frases que dás são uma exceção, porque o artigo não é obrigatório quando o possessivo exprime uma relação de parentesco (mas pelo menos Lisboa é mais comum incluí-lo).

No Brasil, [a situação é diferente](https://veja.abril.com.br/blog/sobre-palavras/a-minha-duvida-cabe-artigo-antes-do-pronome-possessivo/): o artigo tende a ser opcional.

Comment: Eu pensava que era geralmente em todo o Portugal incluir o artigo mesmo com quando o possessivo exprime relação de parentesco. Só me lembro de o ouvir ou ler em discursos ou narrativas com sabor formal ou arcaizante (que pode ser o caso da pergunta; tou a imaginar uma tese de mestrado ou doutoramento).

Comment: @Jacinto Acho que é daquelas coisas que dependem da região. De facto, em Lisboa seria estranho não incluir o artigo. Mas já ouvi pessoas doutras bandas a omitir e é uma "regra" mencionada em vários sítios.